# How to serve some other site in the browser using my server

Tags: web, server, webserver

I have my own server with the domain abc.com. I want to load some other site e.g xyz.com when users visit my website abc.com. I don't want to load xyz.com in an iframe.

I know one website which is doing something like this. The purpose of doing this is to share account access with others without sharing the password.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a Proxy Server, such as [Nginx](https://nginx.org/). It allows you to accept the requests to the domain abc.com and forward those requests to the domain xyz.com.

Reference to Nginx Proxy configuration is [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/).